# MVC Razor doesn't detect LINQ Methods

Tags: razor

I used [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XXXXX), "Init")] in AssemblyInfo.cs.

After built the project, Razor view engine doesn't detect IEnumerable collection Methods like WHERE in editor.

When i commented this line and built project, problem solved.

How i can do, if i want these together?

Comment: what .net framework you using?

Comment: I think, i described badly.
I have no problem in run-time, visual studio 2013 editor doesn't load methods in code-time.

Answer (score 0):

Need to make sure you are referencing and `using System.Linq;` namespaces as LINQ is mostly extension methods.

Comment: I think, i described badly.
I have no problem in run-time, visual studio 2013 editor doesn't load methods in code-time.
you can test it by add this line and use a sample free class.

Comment: oh ok, do you by chance have both VB.net and C# languages loaded in your VS environment?

Comment: No only c#, i wrote a plugin-architect module for my project. after i added this line to assembly.cs to define a class to discover assemblies located in plugins folder, this problem accrued.

Comment: you do it please, add this line  
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XXXXX), "Init")] at the end of assembly.cs, instead of XXXXX use a simple class, then build your project, all of IEnumurable List will fail to load methods.